# Connect to Mongo from Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have Windows PC running two ubuntu virtual machines. One has Meteor installed (app server), to other has Mongo installed (the purpose of this is to use Mongo away from the app server so that it will scale later on). Problem is that I cannot connect to Mongo instance from Meteor!

I can connect to the mongo instance from the the app server when using the line below on the command line and can retrieve data from the collection:

mongo 192.168.56.112/mydb -u myusername -pmypassword

I can also start my meteor app. using:

MONGO_URL="mongodb://myusername:mypassword@192.168.56.112/mydb" meteor

However, when doing the latter, I get an error "ReferenceError: mycollection is not defined".

Can anyone help my to identify why meteor won't connect to mongo?

Comment: Looks like you haven't defined a variable for your collection http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection. Like this: Chatrooms = new Meteor.Collection("chatrooms");

Answer (score 0):

As per Evgeny's suggestion, the answer is to define a variable for my collection:

Chatrooms = new Meteor.Collection("chatrooms");